# Problem with solving simultaneous equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, vectors

[image]

In part v of part a of the question, they asked me to find the coordinates of point P. I know that:

Also note that part v of question relates back to part iv(for context)

- $|OP| = |AP| = |BP| = 5\sqrt{14}$
- $|OP| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
- $|AP| = \sqrt{(x-4)^2 + (y+1)^2 + (z+3)^2}$
- $|BP| = \sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y+4)^2 + (z-1)^2}$

Now I think I should equate them, getting the following:

$[1] x+3y-4z=0$

$[2] -4x+y+3z=-13$

$[3] -3x+4y-z=-13$

But when I put it in the CAS calculator, it gives me this:

$z=z$, $x=z+...$, $y=z+...$

Firstly, what does that mean?

Secondly, however, that cannot be right as I was expecting a single point of intersection. I cannot substitute "$z=z$" into one of the coordinates so where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This means the system of equations proposed is possible but underdetermined. Indeed, this is the case because the third line from the coefficient matrix equals the first line plus the second line. Hence the solution set is the intersection of two planes, whose geometrical interpretation is a line.

Comment: So my method is wrong, I guess? I was expecting a single point of intersection to obtain coordinates.

Comment: @ShootingStars To be honest, I did not read the proposed problem entirely. I just considered the system of equations part. Could you be more specific where did you get stuck?

Comment: I updated the question, look at the picture for context

Comment: You are working with a regular tetrahedron. It's space height from G to P is $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\cdot (leg length)$ That should be more than enough info to get the coordinates of P, using what you know about vectors.